# Get undefined variable trying to update the path to an uploaded file within MongoDB using angular-file-upload and MEAN.js

Tags: mongodb, meanjs, angular-file-upload

If someone could help me I would be eternally grateful.  I have been slamming my head against a brick wall for weeks trying to get images to upload the way it is demonstrated out of the box with the MEAN.js users module.   In the generated users module the file is uploaded into a directory and the path to that file is stored in a field in the mongodb document.  I can get the file to upload to where it needs to go using multer and the fileupload function.  However, I cannot save the path to the field within the document.  I cannot figure out how to avoid getting an 'undefined' variable.  I've tried creating a $window service and passing data to it as a global variable and a bunch of other things and I'm totally stuck.

I have commented the code below to demonstrate what is going awry in my server controller changeShoePicture function.

```
// This is the boilerplate code from the mean.js "users" module.
// I can not create a $window service or global variable to store the 
// shoe data below so that I can update the shoe.shoeImageURL field
// in MongoDB  with path to the successfully uploaded file. 


exports.changeShoePicture = function (req, res) {

var message = null;
var shoe = req.shoe;
var upload = multer(config.uploads.shoeUpload).single('newProfilePicture');
var profileUploadFileFilter = require(path.resolve('./config/lib/multer')).profileUploadFileFilter;

console.log('i am here', shoe); // shoe is defined here.

// Filtering to upload only images. This works and proceeds to the else condition!

upload.fileFilter = profileUploadFileFilter;
upload(req, res, function (uploadError) {   

    if(uploadError) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: 'Error occurred while uploading profile picture'
    });
  } else {

 //shoe image file is successfully uploaded to the location on the server,      
// However the following fails because the shoe variable is undefined.   

shoe.shoeImageURL = config.uploads.shoeUpload.dest + req.file.filename;  
      }
  });
```

Comment: Could you add more debugging, by putting more `console.log(shoe)`? Base on the snippet that you've provided `shoe` is in scope of upload function.

Comment: Do you have your code on public GitHub? This is interesting case...

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I've got this right:

The upload function is being called on your parameters passed by your route, `req` and `res`. You set the `shoe` var from `req.shoe`.

What are the chances that `upload()` is messing with your req?

Drop a `console.log(req)` in right after you call upload and report back

Comment: oKonyk was correct the shoe variable is initially assigned correctly when upload is called.  There's an onsuccess function in the client controller that needs to handle the variable from here.  I'm going to keep digging.  There are many layers of abstraction in the mean.js boilerplate example $window, user, etc.  Documentation is sparse and so are examples outside of strict Angular.  If anyone knows of a CRUD example of how to save images to the file system with multer and the path to a field in a MongoDB document it would be of great service.